# XML to LINQ - Obtaining a node value collection ordered by the value of another element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, fluent

I have the following XML I only need to grab the `Id` node value but I do need to grab them in order by `DatePaid` node

```
<Payment>
    <Id>47398</Id>
    <DatePaid>09/01/2019 10:44:08</DatePaid>
</Payment>
<Payment>
    <Id>63523</Id>
    <DatePaid>09/07/2019 10:04:02</DatePaid>
</Payment>
<Payment>
    <Id>94902</Id>
    <DatePaid>09/05/2019 10:32:09</DatePaid>
</Payment>
```

So the resulting list will be in this order

```
47398
94902
63523
```

I thought this would be the way to do it using LINQ fluent syntax

```
XDocument xResults = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);
List<string> sortedRecordIds = xResults.Descendants("Id")
                                .OrderBy(d => DateTime.Parse(d.Element("DatePaid").Value).Date)
                                .Select(d => d.Value)
                                .ToList();
```

But this throws an exception. Am I using the sort incorrectly?

Comment: What kind of exception? Please provide.

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` - Usually occurs when there is a problem with the LINQ statement

Comment: The error occures because you are using "Id" as Decendants. Switch to "Payment" it should work fine. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use XMLDocument insteed of XDocument, you can achive this like so.

Your XML (I think you have a Root Element):

```
<root>
    <Payment>
        <Id>47398</Id>
        <DatePaid>09/01/2019 10:44:08</DatePaid>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <Id>63523</Id>
        <DatePaid>09/07/2019 10:04:02</DatePaid>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <Id>94902</Id>
        <DatePaid>09/05/2019 10:32:09</DatePaid>
    </Payment>
</root>
```

Code to get as you need:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml( myXmlString );
List<string> list = xmlDocument.ChildNodes[ 0 ]
    .OfType<XmlNode>()
    .OrderBy( payment => DateTime.Parse( payment.ChildNodes[ 1 ].InnerText ) )
    .Select( payment => payment.ChildNodes[ 0 ].InnerText )
    .ToList();
```

**Update**
Change your code to get it working:

```
List<string> sortedRecordIds = xResults.Descendants("Payment")
    .OrderBy( d => DateTime.Parse( d.Element( "DatePaid" ).Value ).Date )
    .Select( d => d.Element("Id").Value )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a reason it cannot be done in `XDocument`? I would like to figure out why I am getting the error when trying to use `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);
List<string> sortedRecordIds = xDoc.Descendants("Payment")
                                .OrderBy(d => d.Element("DatePaid").Value)
                                .Select(d => d.Element("Id").Value)         
                                .ToList();
```

My issue was that I should have been using `Payment` instead of `Id`. When starting at the `Id` node there was no `DatePaid` element to sort on.